# Opportunities in machine learning and computational intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, careers

I'm not sure this is the right site to post my question. If not, please direct me to the right one.

I'm interested in machine learning and computational intelligence. I've spent the last year of my free time on personal projects in computation intelligence (neural networks and genetic algorithms).

I'm currently working as developer. The programming tasks have become boring, and I'm looking to move on. I don't think I can continue being a developer unless it is in the field of computational intelligence.

I now have the idea of doing freelance in computational intelligence. However, I do not have a good idea where to start looking.

**Edit**
The question is where do I look for opportunities? I'm mainly interested in finding freelance work.

PS. I have also posted to Data Science, but had no answers https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5866/opportunities-in-machine-learning-and-computational-intelligence

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as @Ramalho said try looking at http://www.kaggle.com/ for competitions

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the party!!! Yay :-) 
There are plenty of competitions on kaggle, physionet, etc.. and data science jobs are everywhere (the world needs more data scientists), granted that you are a capable data scientist you may get an internship or job. Publishing your projects on github is also a good idea.

Comment: Where do you start looking for those jobs? One major issue for me is that I don't have a degree. Also I thought that maybe I should not be looking for a job at all. Try to go down the rabbit hole of self-employment.

Comment: In my case I didnt  looked for one, I add contact with a team working on a GIS solution and presented solutions for real time streaming analytics over motion data, i got in. Most products are struggling with pattern recognition tasks, you find them a solution and they will be eating from you hands. Anyway stack careers has plenty of offers.